# Is it ok to define PDO db connection in function?

Tags: php, database, function, pdo, connection

I am thinking, is it safe and OK to use db connection in function to return it anywhere in the project? If I want to reuse this project to build another one, I can change db connection only in this function and I don't need to go all over the script searching and changing connection parameter.

```
function connect_db(){
$db = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=;charset=utf8', '', '');
return $db;
}
```

Now I can call it anywhere functions.php file is required once, by returning

```
$db = connect_db();
```

and then whatever statement follows.

Is it ok and safe?

And how to close connection like this at the end of the page?

```
 $db = NULL;
```

apparently won't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is safe and ok to have a single place that creates a connection to your database. I would change your function just a bit though:

```
<?php
function connect_db(){
    try{
        return new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=mydb', 'username', 'password', array(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND =>'SET NAMES utf8'));
    }catch (PDOException $e){
        echo '<p>Error connecting to database! ' . $e->getMessage() . '</p>';
        die();
    }
}
?>
```

You can read more about the PDO constructor in the [documentation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.construct.php).

And to [close the PDO connection](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.connections.php) created this way you do indeed just:

```
<?php
$pdo = NULL;
?>
```

Please note that there is really a lot more to be said on this subject. Ideally you would have a class that handles the creation of your PDO object(s). You might want to take a look at [this excellent answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4595964/who-needs-singletons/4596323#4596323) from [Gordon](https://stackoverflow.com/users/208809/gordon) as a place to start.

Comment: for closing connection this variable $pdo isn't defined in function is that a typo?

Comment: @grab My `$pdo` is equivalent to your `$db` - I just used a different variable name, sorry about the confusion.